# Delete mongodb document by id in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm pulling my hair for this...trying to delete document by id:

```
router.delete('/api/menu/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  db.get().collection('menu', function (err, col) {
   col.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(id)});
  });
  res.json({ success: id })
});
```

Always getting :

```
Cannot read property deleteOne of undefined
```

When trying to find records it's working as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it.
First thing i require the mongodb

```
mongo = require('mongodb')
```

And then :

```
router.delete('/api/menu/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var collection = db.get().collection('menu');

  collection.deleteOne({ _id: new mongo.ObjectId(id) }, function (err, results) {
  });

  res.json({ success: id })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that col is undefined.
Probably you are getting the collection in a wrong way. If you are using the official mongo driver, try to change method collection by createCollection, like this:

```
router.delete('/api/menu/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  db.get().createCollection('menu', function (err, col) {
   col.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(id)});
  });
  res.json({ success: id })
});
```

Comment: If I want to delete mutilple id how to delete it

Comment: If you need to do it in just one method, probably is better to create an specific method for that and pass all the ids in a field in the body