# Issue with posts only becoming deletable after a page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fetch

I created a todo-list that runs on NodeJS, MongoDB, and a vanilla html,css,js frontend. A user can make posts and delete posts. On load, the website fetches the json for the all the posts saved to the database and calls a load function. My current issue is that when I delete a recently added task, it stays in the database after reload but is removed from the html. If I delete a task that has already been loaded in from MongoDB, it deletes as intended.

I've looked into it and I'm not entirely sure. The application loads all objects from MongoDB into an array, then adds any user submitted tasks into the array, posting them to my api on submit. The delete command sends a delete request to my api then removes it from the array and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the unique id (_id) provided by mongo when you add a record to the database. You can use the same unique ID while making a delete request to your API.

This might help: [Delete mongodb document by id in express js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164208/delete-mongodb-document-by-id-in-express-js)

Comment: Thank you, I missed that I wasn't assigning the _id on submit is there a way to grab the _id while it is posted to MongoDB or would  I have to request the whole object again?

Comment: You can map the _id you get from mongoDB response object to a local variable on the frontend when you make the initial GET request to display all your todos.

Comment: That would still require a reload from the user and I don't see a point in making a request every time an item is added.

Comment: This might help. https://webapplog.com/todo-app-with-express-jsnode-js-and-mongodb/

Comment: Never mind, I realized that the Post request gives a response of the object created, so I can just grab the _id from there.